# jQuery based countdown timer

Tags: jquery

Looking for a jQuery countdown timer that is easy to work with. I need to supply the number of minutes to countdown from i.e. 5 min to 0 etc.

Found several here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/tags.php?/countdown/ but I am unable to find one that is easy to use.

Could anyone possibly help identify one that is easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

"Easy to use" is kind of subjective, but I like The Final Countdown. Check it out here :
http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

Implementation is only a few lines of code and it has extensive documentation on the website, including installation instructions.

Comment: thanks, this is good but it says finalDate, where what i require is basically in minutes as in start countdown timer for 5 minutes from now or 10 minutes from now. how does that get done.

Comment: Sounds like the finalDate argument would be something along the lines of var newFinalDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + diff*60000);
Where "diff" is your number of minutes from now.